# Is it possible to retrieve and post data in same form?? python flask and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-mysql

I have a python flask form. Where in first input field with search button when I enter the id and click button it should fill the remaining fileds retriving from database. and then if ok it should be edited and then again on submit it needs to be saved into database.
I'm using python flask and MySQL.

Help me please!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes its possible. You need to do like this, load the page with empty values first, then insert an id in a search box. When search button is clicked, post a search query in the backend and load the values from query result to its respective field in the page. Edit something and click submit button and it will update. All done in form

Comment: yeah! got it but how to load the values from query and where to add that??

Comment: We need to see your code in order for us to know what you're working with. Now your question is too broad; which means there are a lot of ways to achieve what you want. So, if you post the code you're working with, we can figure out some method that can be implemented with your code. No need to post the whole codes, just post something that is relevant. Once you have the code ready, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62607041/edit) and put in the codes. Throw in your expected output as well, good luck!